# Modern List web part on modern page will not show all items automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-pages

I configured my list to display something large, 150 items even though there are less than 50 items to display.

I add my list to a modern page and configure "Autosize - fit to number of items."

It appears it only displays 30 items until I scroll down with the page AND the list (it still acts a bit quirky to get it to display more when you do scroll).  Is there a way to have it display all of the items in the view without having to scroll down with two scrollbars?  You can see all the white space in the image is where there are additional items, but they're not displaying.  Argh.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my test I have the same experience with you, there is no way to have it display all of the items in the view without having to scroll down with two scrollbars.

Comment: Not a big fan of this behavior.  It's not "fit to the number of items" if it's actually only 30.

Comment: When we scroll down with the two scroll bars, it will display more than 30 items.

Comment: It does, but not very cleanly.